# React.CloneElement - not rendering the cloned element

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a wrapper which will inject a prop to his children, without adding another layer of html element (like div/span)
so I've used React.cloneElement passed it the children and prop to inject,
and it's not rendering the children at all!

what have I done wrong?

here is the wrapper code:

```
export const Wrapper = ({children}:{children:JSX.Element}) => {
  return React.cloneElement(children, {somePropFromWrapper: 'Yoo!'}, null);
};
```

and when I'm trying to use it:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <ChildrenComponent id="children-id"> 
                the children inner html
            </ChildrenComponent> 
        <Wrapper>
    )
}
```

it's not rendering the children at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Hi @noer,

You should **pass** the children **prop** to `React.cloneElement` as the **third argument**. This will ensure that the `children` of the Wrapper component are passed through to the cloned element.

```js
export const Wrapper = ({children}: {children: JSX.Element}) => {
  return React.cloneElement(children, {somePropFromWrapper: 'Yoo!'}, children);
};
```

Your `ChildrenComponent` should be rendered properly inside the Wrapper component.

> In Your Previous code, you are using the third argument to `Wrapper` component, which is `null`. That means the cloned element will not have any children, that is why your children component is not being the rendered.

Here please read this:- [**React-CloneElement**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Comment: Hey! 
thanks for the response, 
the children should be the first + the last element? 
it wouldn't wrap the children element (last argument) wrapped inside another children element (first argument)?

Comment: If you pass a single child element as the third argument, the cloned element will have that element as its only child. If you pass an array of child elements, the cloned element will have those elements as its children.